# 3xVector3 -> [Vector3; 3]

Tags: vector, rust

```
pub struct Vector3 {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    pub z: f32,
}

impl Vector3 {
    pub fn from(pos: [f32; 3]) -> Self {
        Self {
            x: pos[0],
            y: pos[1],
            z: pos[2]
        }
    }
}

pub fn matrix(&self) -> [Vector3; 3] {
    let mut vector1: [f32; 3] = [0.0; 3];
    let mut vector2: [f32; 3] = [0.0; 3];
    let mut vector3: [f32; 3] = [0.0; 3];
    vector1 = [0.0; 0.0; 0.0];
    vector2 = [1.0; 1.0; 1.0];
    vector3 = [0.2; 0.2; 0.2];
    let mut vec1 = Vector3::from(vector1);
    let mut vec2 = Vector3::from(vector2);
    let mut vec3 = Vector3::from(vector3);
    
    ...
}
```

Как мне правильно вернуть значение, ломаю голову, не могу сообразить=)

Answer (score -1):

Всё сообразил=)
нужно просто добавить:

```
[vec1, vec2, vec3]
```